# built in spark does not work on crontab

Tags: apache-spark, cron, built-in

I use Spark by builtin-java classes on a single machine.

I have a trouble with crontab to run spark-submit.

'/user/test.sh'

```
#! /bin/bash
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit test.jar
```

and 'crontab -e'

```
45 16  *  *  * /user/a.sh           >> /user/log/test.log
```

Then, 'test.log' is empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue myself.

I added below into 'test.sh' file.

export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME:/app/jdk/bin/

It may not have been find jdk path.